Is there anyway to preserve field names when compiling proto schemas?
I have some legacy code in JS and C# and refactoring it doesn't seem possible, and I want to switch to protobuf from json but the issue is protobuf is changing field names based on language. In C# it is generating pascal case and in JS it is generating camel case. I checked and didn't find any flag which keeps the original field names which are given in the proto files.
I had an idea of creating custom plugin where plugin sets the field names and forwards it to other plugins but after bit of research seems like that is not possible either.
Has anyone faced any such issue and found any solution?

Yes, you can usually configure JSON serialization to|from protobuf messages to preserve protobuf field names. I'm less familiar with using protobufs with C#, which library are you using. Please update your question to provide more context.... The JSON you're trying to achieve (or a representation of this) etc.

With apologies for my lack of familiarity with the C# library, it appears (!?) there's a Settings property PreserveProtoFieldNames on the JsonFormatter.
